# Using VideoJS to play wowza stream on IE for windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, video.js, wowza

I am trying to use VideoJs to publish Video On Demand on my website.

The Streaming server is Wowza.

This is the code of my webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.1/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="480" height="270" 
         poster="http://websiteURL/image.png" 
         data-setup="{}">
        <source src="rtmp://serverURL/mediacache&mp4:http/fileUrl.mp4" type="rtmp/mp4" />
        <source src="http://serverURL/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:http/fileUrl.mp4/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works correctly on

- Google Chrome (PC, MAC, Android )
- Firefox (PC, MAC)
- Firefox (PC, MAC)
- IE11 (PC)
- Safari (MAC, iOS)

But on Windows Phone 8.1 does not work and the video player shows this error: "the media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported."
I tryed, without success, to add this source for using Microsoft Smooth Streaming:

```
<source src="http://serverURL/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:http/fileUrl.mp4/Manifest" type="video/smooth">
```

I also tried to change type to "video/x-m4v" but nothing changed.

Any idea? thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

IE on Windows phone supports none of those formats.

It's possible that [videojs-contrib-hls](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls), which adds HLS support to browsers via MSE can play the HLS stream on Windows Phone.

Comment: I tryed to use hls library but without success. Now the console error is: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.